# Responsive Menu Vertical Center Text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, fluid-layout

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BL5vd/

I'm trying to create a responsive menu with 4 links. The links should be VERTICALLY centered and the `a` should be larger as the `li`.

`line-height: 100%` on the `ul li a` doesn't work, unfortunately. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

here is a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3hSLc/)
html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Link</span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Link</span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Link</span></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Link</span></a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

css (changed part):

```
ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background: orange;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
ul li a span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `table-cell`. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/5deF5/)

CSS

```
ul {
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

ul li {
    height: 25%;
    display:table-row;
}

ul li a {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    background: orange;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
}
```